# Could not initialize English Chunker

Tags: java, languagetool

I have included LanguageTool coding in my Java Maven project as below;

**Java Code**

```
    List<Language> realLanguages = Languages.get();
    for (Language language : realLanguages) {
        System.out.println(language.getName() + " ==> " + language.getShortName());
        if (language.getName().startsWith("English (US)")) {
            JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(language);

            PatternRuleLoader patternRuleLoader = new PatternRuleLoader();
            List<PatternRule> abstractPatternRuleList = new ArrayList<PatternRule>();
            abstractPatternRuleList = patternRuleLoader.getRules(new File(LTPath + "/CustomGrammar.xml"));

            System.out.println("\n\nDefault Active Rules: " + langTool.getAllActiveRules().size());

                    <-- More coding goes here -->
```

and it works absolutely fine when the module's jar is invoked from one project (on server 'A'), but the same throws the below attached exception, "Could not initialize English chunker" when invoked from another (on server 'B').

**Dependency**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
            <artifactId>language-en</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Exception**

[image: Could not initialize English chunker]

Please help !

Comment: you need to add the jar to your classpath

Comment: @ScaryWombat You are a very Scary Wombat indeed. Scary how you deduced that so easily :-)

Comment: Actually it is the SAXParser that is not found - you need to add the jar to your classpath

Comment: @clearlight A master of sarcasm perhaps? Or am I just the master of stating the bloody obvious ;-)